# How to get all props of native component when create new component with typescript interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

It's maybe the simple question but honestly i don’t  know how to do that

For exmaple i have a custom `TextInput` from react native called `CustomTextInput`

And it will have an interface

```
export interface CustomTextInputI{
 customPlaceHolder:string
 style:ViewStyle
 //etc
}
```

And i use it like

```
export const CustomTextInput =(props:CustomTextInputI)=>(
    const {customPlaceHolder, style} = props
     
    return(
     <TextInput style={style}. etc />
    )
)
```

And use this componet like `<CustomTextInput style customPlaceHolder/>`
**BUT** if i use a textInput props like secureTextEntry, it will not accecpt (of course)   so how can i use my custom props plus **`all props of TextInput`**. ???

Comment: Try `{...etc}` instead

Comment: @LeriGogsadze  i mean ect stand for any other props, but if i want to access TextInput props , it wont wont, i tried `{...secureTextEntry} for example, but wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work:

```
import { TextInputProps } from 'react-native'
   
export interface CustomTextInputI extends TextInputProps {
```